# i want RPi will give internet to my desktop

Tags: bluetooth

I'm struggling to get internet in Desktop from Raspberry Pi.
Same steps as from mobile Bluetooth to Desktop try to access internet worked. Any solution tell me.

[image: Screenshot taken while Accessing Internet through my mobile Bluetooth]

[image: Screenshot taken while Accessing Internet through my RPi Bluetooth]

Comment: Have you looked into **blueman**? Also look into https://www.hkepc.com/forum/viewthread.php?tid=1710030 and https://forums.raspberrypi.com//viewtopic.php?f=36&t=57529

Comment: thanks @colpanic , i tried and I'm stocked in this step i don't have eth0 I'm having pan0 and wlan0 while editing this file /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: bnep0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.X.X.X  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.X.X.X
        inet6 X::X:X:X:X  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether X:X:X:X:X:X  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 151  bytes 15015 (14.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 76  bytes 12203 (11.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 25  bytes 2823 (2.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25  bytes 2823 (2.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: pan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 4096
        inet 7.7.7.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 7.7.7.255
        inet6 X::X:X:X:X  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether X:X:X:X:X:X  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 151  bytes 13747 (13.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 101  bytes 13614 (13.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500 inet 192.168.113.75  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast x  inet6 X::X:X:X:X  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>   inet6 X:X:X:X:X:X:X:X  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0                                                                                                           <global>    ether e4:5f:01:8f:67:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)  RX packets 10  bytes 1094 (1.0 KiB)  RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0   TX packets 44  bytes 4719 (4.6 KiB) TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149451/discussion-on-question-by-premanand-patro-i-want-rpi-will-give-internet-to-my-de); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.